# Localizing the app, but not so much. A problem with dates

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

One of our apps is only available in Italy; so, currently, the only available language is Italian. All strings are Italian, but it is a common practice for many users to set the device in another language (e.g., English).
When formatting `LocalDate`s with a `DateTimeFormatter`, or `Date`s with `DateUtils`, we obtain, by default, all strings translated in the `Locale.getDefault()`'s locale.

The result is an Italian app with some parts in another language, for users which don't have Italian as the default locale.

We thought of two different solutions but I would like to get an opinion or suggestions for other approaches.

The first solution we thought of has been to set for the whole app a default locale, by taking the locale's tag from the `values/strings.xml` file. Since in the future there will be other supported languages, each language would have its proper locale tag and the app would always use the same language for each string.

Another approach is to define a generic interface named `CustomDateFormatter`, implement it with an `ItalianCustomDateFormatter`, inject it and, in the future, replace it with an `InternationalCustomDateFormatter`.

Do you have some suggestions on this problem? How you'd solve (or have solved) it?

Comment: Why not just use `Locale.US` as locale while formatting date ?

Comment: Because there're a lot of dates within the app, we need a uniform way to get them.

Comment: Again same thing,  Create a separate class for formatting dates it will be a Singleton probably and u can change the locale any time in future with just one variable change. And this is the uniform way to do this.   that is why its good to follow SOLID ..